# jQuery's .ajax() not working with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to troubleshoot this, but can't find a good function that will execute a full stack trace. Here's what I have so far:

Javascript (in page `/charts/userbase.php`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/data/users.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function() {
      console.log("I'm hitting an error.");
    },
    success: function(jsonData) {
      // do something
    }
});
```

/data/users.php (should dump JSON)

```
<?php
  //some processing precedes this
  $data = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
  $data = str_replace("\/", "/", $data);
  $data = str_replace("\"", "", $data);

  header("Content-type: application/json");
  echo $data;

?>
```

Visiting 127.0.0.1/data/users.php returns the correct JSON, but somehow I can't get jQuery's `$.ajax()` to work, and I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to output a stack trace if it fails. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Damn, that was a lot of responses, really fast.

First off, I do post-procession on the JSON string because PHP keeps changing `/` into `\/`, which JS's native `Date()` can't handle, and it keeps adding `"`, which breaks parts of the code expecting booleans. I have already verified that it is returning the correct output.

Second, changing `error` to add `jsonData` prints out `undefined`, and the `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` returns an object, with `status` 200.

Maybe I'm wrong and it's not the ajax call, but I'm way more confused now.

**EDIT 2:** Running with `console.log(arguments)`, I'm getting a `parseError`. I'll take a closer look, but I don't see anything wrong with what I have.

**Last Edit:** Turns out everyone was right on that last line; shouldn't have replaced the `"`. Still need `str_replace("\/", "/", $data)` though. I feel pretty dumb it took me a few hours to troubleshoot this, though.

Comment: Does the `console.log` statement execute? Why not use the `error` function's parameters: `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`

Comment: You are modifying the json string after using json_encode.  Why are you doing this and are you sure that it's still a valid json string after this modification?

Comment: Need more info about what the $.ajax call does or doesn't do.

Comment: As @Jody said, you're very likely corrupting the JSON string with your `str_replace` lines.

Comment: Remember that the error parameter doesn't just automatically know that generically "something went wrong". It means that a server error was returned. The server can be successfully returning something that your success function doesn't handle, and the error message will still never alert.

Comment: "I have already verified that it is returning the correct output" - how? which validator of the JSON string did you use? and can you post the results of JSON.stringify(jsonData); from within the success:

Comment: There is a reason that `json_encode` adds slashes and quotes the way it does.  I suggest removing those `str_replace` lines and verifying that your script can actually parse the JSON.

Comment: Also, please include the actual JSON string that you're working with.

Comment: @Edwin - may I recommend that you do not use `str_replace` at all in the PHP.  Fix this problem in the javascript, before creating your Date(), on the specific element which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

What happens if you try

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data/users.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function() {
      console.log("I'm hitting an error.");
      console.log(arguements);
    },
    success: function(jsonData) {
      // do something
      console.log(jsonData);
    }
});
```

You should see console logs stating an error occurred because you are modifying the json string after you encoded it.

EDIT:

You say your JSON is good. Try using this to verify http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Edwin - or `console.log(arguments)`

Comment: Refering someone to the overall documentation shouldn't quite qualify as an answer - this might be better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

can you add this to your ajax:

`contentType: "application/json",`